# How to use dynamic lists in a recursive function in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, alpha-beta-pruning

I have a dynamic list storing a field coordinate and owner of that field

```
:-dynamic
    board/2.
```

One entry of this list looks like that:

```
board(e4,[w]).
```

There are 22 more board positions all looking similar.

I am trying to implement an AI for the game the board is for.
I am using the alpha beta algorithm and therefore have to create new 'boards' to evalate the situation.

I have a copy of the original board to work with but now have a function adjusting the board for the current move like this:

```
move(position,boardOld,boardNew)
```

This is called recursive therefore in second call boardOld equals boardNew and boardNew is the oldBoard with the next move in the analysis.

My idea was to copy the old Board in every iteration, but i have no idea how to do this as this

```
copy_predicate_clauses(boardOld(A,B),boardNew(A,B)).
```

would add the old Board to the newBoard because the list already exists.

I am using the following algorithm (can't copy it, as it is an image):

http://www.cuceinetwork.net/archivos/prolog/The_Art_of_Prolog.pdf

PDF page 445 (Book page 407).

The algorithm gets Position as 'Board' while initializing, i don't know how to do this with my list and furthermore the clause move(Move,Position,Position1) return the new Board with the current move. This is called recursive and i have no idea how to create the board for position1 without overwriting the ones from before.

Edit//

ok, i get the problem. But i already used this predicate a lot in my game and don't want to change it all. I did this:

```
findall((X,Y),board(X,Y),CurrentBoard).
```

CurrentBoard gives me a list like this

```
[(e4,[w,w]),(g4,[s,w]),(b7,[r,w,s])]
```

Now i can't use my methods to determine the possible moves.

I have facts like

```
move(e4,d5).
move(d5,e6).
```

stating which move(from,to) is possible and now i tried this

```
findall((X,Y),listMoves(CurrentBoard,X,Y),possibleMoves).
```

with something like this. I am struggeling at this point. How do i generate a list with possible moves. I somehow have to get the X coordinate from currentBoard, check if the Head of the list from that coordinate (pawns on that coordinate) belongs to me and check if the Y coordinate (to) is free.

```
listMoves([Coordinate|[Head|Tail]], X, Y) :-
     move(X,Y),
     ownField(X,Coordinate,Head),
```

Comment: This is very difficult (if not impossible) to answer given the lack of details.

Comment: I will edit the question and share more details

Comment: Your problem is that you're trying to treat the dynamic store as a list (you say so yourself, but `board/2` is a predicate, not a list) and it isn't really fit for that purpose. You'd be better of making explicit lists for your board state and passing those around, because manipulating actual lists is much easier than manipulating facts in the dynamic store.

Comment: I edited my thread with some thoughts...But struggeling again

Comment: `possibleMoves` is an atom, not a variable, in Prolog. :)

Comment: Also, `[Coordinate|[Head|Tail]]` is equivalent to `[Coordinate,Head|Tail]` which is probably not what you want. In fact, this may help illustrate why it is unwise to use `,/2` as if Prolog has pairs; you can too easily confuse yourself.

Comment: IMO you are getting to the right track, though I think if you bridge half your code to passing the board and not the other half you will only create new problems for yourself down the road. The key is to pass the board state to something to generate possible moves. Then you can select one and use it to generate a new board state.

Comment: But i somehow have to use pairs? I am not quite sure if i get your idea how to determine the possible moves...can't i use my `CurrentBoard` and extract them? Do you have an idea how to generate moves assuming from X to Y with pawn colour w? I think I don't get your idea how to do this...quite late in europe already will check for answers tomorrow..thanks though

Answer (score 1):

If you read from (printed) page 401, the authors outline the basic gameplay algorithm as:

> ```
>    play(Game) :-
>          initialize(Game, Position, Player),
>          display_game(Position, Player),
>          play(Position, Player, Result).
> ```

The rest of the section uses the term "position" in a way that makes me believe they are referring to the entire state of the game. For a game like chess, this would be the state of the board itself: what pieces are where.

From there, the authors go on to discuss `move/2` and `move/3`, which are defined thusly:

> It is convenient to separate the choice of the move by `choose_move/3` from its execution by `move/3`

And then later on page 403,

> The predicate `move(Position, Move)` is true if `Move` is a possible move from the current position.

Taken together, this all suggests to me that they expect a `Position` to be the complete chess board (I think you're playing chess, are you?) and `Move` to be a legitimate move, for the purposes of defining `move/2`, and then `move/3` is just `move/2`, returning the resultant board. In other words, the initial chessboard might look something like this:

```
starting_board([[b-r, b-b, b-n, b-q, b-k, b-n, b-b, b-r],
                [b-p, b-p, b-p, b-p, b-p, b-p, b-p, b-p],
                [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
                [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
                [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
                [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
                [w-p, w-p, w-p, w-p, w-p, w-p, w-p, w-p],
                [w-r, w-b, w-n, w-q, w-k, w-n, w-b, w-r]]).
```

This is how I might set it up; doubtless there are probably more efficient or wiser ways of doing it, but the point is, your `Position` values should always encompass the whole state of the board like this. In fact, it may need to include other information, like whose turn it is, or if you wanted to keep a log of each move, you could throw that in there as well.

From here, you're prepared to write `move/2` and `move/3`. I would be inclined (for didactic purposes) to just write `move/3` and use that to build `move/2` but for efficiency you probably want to do them separately. I'm bad enough at chess that I'm going to stop here (that and I am not convinced you're doing chess anyway). But basically, what you want is to see that `move(StartPosition, Move, NewPosition)`, given a start position, will unify `Move` with some sort of short description of the move and `NewPosition` with the whole board state after having made that move, so you get a before-and-after snapshot.

Once you have these parts built I think you can mostly use the book code as-is.

I think you basically had a few misunderstandings:

1. The board is not a predicate with multiple solutions. It's a data structure you create that represents the whole story of what's going on.
2. Dynamic predicates do not form a list. It's true that you can have multiple solutions and that they have an order, it is not a convenient data structure for the kinds of manipulations you're going to need to do.
3. I really don't think you want to mix those two ideas together and see what falls out.